# Rewrite problems with custom website and wordpress

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I am managing a website tasteporto.com that is simple php/mysql with a blog part in wordpress.

On the main website I have the following apache rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# no-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

# if not blog, make URLs pretty
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\/blog\/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# if not blog, make URLs pretty by removing file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\/blog\/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

On the wordpress directory I have the standard rules plus one to make sure that it is being applied to the blog path:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/blog\/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/blog\/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

All normal links on the website work fine, as well as the starter page for the blog.

The problem is that Wordpress's permalinks like 
    https://tasteporto.com/blog/ready-for-sao-joao/
do this
    https://www.tasteporto.com/http:/www.tasteporto.com/

I know this is something stupidly simple, but I've been looking at the same problem for too long and could use some help.
Can anybody offer some wisdom please?

Thank you from rewrite hell

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but i think your problem is relating to missing the blog URL in either RewriteBase or RewriteRule (or both). `RewriteBase /blog` and `RewriteRule ^/blog/index\.php$ - [L]`. Then your RewriteConditions for the blog URL might be unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @SteffenNielsen, that did not work, I'm afraid. Still fighting with this.

Comment: Could it be, that you have not configured Wordpress itself to know it's location under /blog? Like mentioned in this article https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/install-wordpress-subdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

May be problem derived from following rules:

```
# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

Please try change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, I really appreciate them.

After some trial and error I figured it out. The problem was the baseline for the rewrite rules in the blog part of things.

To start with, something that helped was increased logging to the access and error log files. So in /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load I added the second line below:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace4
```

Then here are the rewrites in the website config file in sites-available:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Turn on HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# No-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And here is the .htaccess on the main website:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if not blog do make URLs pretty
# by removing .php extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\/blog\/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And finally the .htaccess on the blog directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteRule ^/blog/index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

The main problem was this last bit with the RewriteBase having changed to /blog.

I hope this helps others.